# Sybase: Get the first data in a Group

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I'm having a problem getting the first row data in group in my data collection. Currently I'm using Sybase as my datasource.

I also used below query but not working.

```
SELECT Id, Product, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id) FROM ProductTbl

SELECT Id, Product FROM ProductTbl as X
WHERE Id = (
SELECT min(Id)
  FROM ProductTbl WHERE Id = X.Id
)
```

Below example are the data that I'm working on.

```
Id     Product  
1111    Apple  
1111    Orange  
1111    Banana  
2222    Guava  
2222    JackFruit  
2222    Grape  
3333    ProductA  
3333    ProductB
```

My expected output should be

```
Id      Product
1111    Apple
2222    Guava
3333    ProductA
```

Comment: on what criteria you select product (eg: `apple` for `1111`)

Comment: My requirement is to get the first row of the Id, regardless of ProductName (product)

Comment: id is fine but you may have problem with getting correct product because of ordering. Problem will occur in case of `id 2222` where order by clause will give `grape` instead of `Guava`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
SELECT Id, MIN(Product) FROM ProductTbl GROUP BY Id
```

Have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

```
select Id,Product from(
SELECT 
    Id,
    Product, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Product) as first_row 
FROM ProductTbl group by Id,Product)x 
where first_row = 1
```

Output:

```
Id   Product
1111,Apple
2222,Grape
3333,ProductA
```

R comes before U, so it cant be Guava.

Comment: Try just the select : SELECT 
    Id,
    Product, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Product) as first_row 
FROM ProductTbl